# MySQL won't configure, incorrect root password?

Tags: mysql

So i've installed MySQL server 5.6, and it just will not let me in as it keeps telling me i've got the root password wrong on the installer.

I may or may not have used another MySQL server before, but have long since deleted it and set a new root password upon installing this new server.

Since it wasn't letting me in, i decided to see if there was another way to find out my password (which there isn't) or change it (which there is) but this hasn't worked either. 
This is the document i was using.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

I have changed my password multiple times now, it's accepted it according to the command prompt, and yet it still won't let me use SQL server...

Oh and i am on the administrator's account. How do i find out, or fix the root password permanently?

Answer (score 2):

Okay i've finally figured out how to solve this (and in turn get it to install fully!).

What i did was delete everything from my system relating to MySQL, uninstall it and then re-download the installer. When installing i created a new file location and made MySQL install under C:\MySQL (a new folder i made), rather than let it install into C:\Program Files... and this seemed to make it install immediately, and meant that it couldn't find (if they were still there) any previously made root passwords.

Answer (score 0):

The key to what it says in that link is to *run it as administrator* in the Windows sense. Otherwise it all appears to work but it reverts itself when you exit.

Comment: I do run it as an admin, it doesn't work anyway (i run both cmd and sql server as admin)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue. If you go into the installer and remove MYSQL Server and re-install, it will allow you to set the root password again and continue with your configurations.